# Roots of an irreducible polynomial in an extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

So I have just got into Algebra and I intuitively understand the idea of an extension. However, I am struggling in answering this certain question. In $GF(2)$, it is known that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible. However, we can extend this field such that $x^2+x+1$ has a root. A trivial extension would be the complex field and we would get two complex roots using the qudratic formula. However, if we were to extend our base field to $GF(2^4) = GF(16)$ and then reduce it by $x^4 + x +1$. What would the roots of $x^2+x+1$ be in this extension field?

EDIT:

Thank to Wuestenfux, I do understand extension field better now. However, how do you figure out that $\beta^5$ and $\beta^{10}$ are roots of the polynomial in the extension field?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The complex field would not be an extension of $GF(2)$, since the complex field does not contain $GF(2)$ as a subfield.

The polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2)$ and it splits in $GF(4)$ into linear factors. For this, let $\alpha$ be a root. Then $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$ and so $GF(4)=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$.

The field $GF(16)$ contains $GF(4)$ as a subfield. If $\beta$ is a root of the (primitive) irreducible polynomial $x^4+x+1$ over $GF(2)$, the elements of $GF(16)$ are $0,1,\beta,\ldots,\beta^{14}$.
In particular, $0,1,\beta^5,\beta^{10}$ are the elements of the subfield $GF(4)$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about the complex field. I see how the build up works. However, how do you know that $x^2 +x +1$ splits into linear factors in GF(4)? especially that the elements of GF(4) are 0,1 $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$

Comment: For construction purposes choose a primitive polynomial (and both polynomials above are primitive), then the extension field consists of 0 and the powers of a zero of the primitive polynomial.

Comment: I see. Here lies my other confusion, how do we assume that $\beta$ is a root of the primitive polynomial where by definition, a primitive polynomial is irreducible. Do you see my confusion?

Comment: Primitive polynomials always exist.

Comment: I am aware of this fact, but they're irreducible hence no roots exist. right?

Comment: Its a basic fact that if an irreducible polynomial has a root in a finite field, all of its roots lie in that field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107360/discussion-between-anonymous-and-wuestenfux).

Comment: Sorry but no time.